# JAVA POI failed to write a large word file

Tags: java

### I am using POI to delete "enter" in a .doc file (Blank line).

My code below works correctly when the input file is not large (for example, less than 1MB). However, when I deal with large input.doc that is 4mb, the output.doc is not correctly generated. I can not open the file.

Does anyone have better idea to write the big file correctly? Or, is there any other java code that can delete "enter" in a big .doc file? Thank you very much.

```
package mydoc;

import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test {
/*The ASCII of "Enter" is 13*/
private static final short ENTER_ASCII = 13;

public static void main(String[] args){
    /* the location of the input file   */
    String fileName = "D:\\input.doc";

    deleteEnter(fileName);
}

public static void deleteEnter(String fileName){

    POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
    try{
        fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);            

        Range range = doc.getRange();

        for (int i = 0; i < range.numParagraphs(); i++) 
        {
            if (range.getParagraph(i).text().toCharArray()[0]==ENTER_ASCII)
            {  
                range.getParagraph(i).delete();
            } 
        }                                           

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\output.doc"));

        doc.write(fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    }//end try
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//end catch
}
```

}

Comment: what is the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs you could even use a macro;
You should even be able to use regex like this: "^13{2,}", but that didn't work for me in Word 2010, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d921f97-b59a-48a9-a01a-20fe72f21c19/how-to-remove-blank-lines-?forum=worddev

```
Sub RemoveBlankLines()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .MatchWildcards = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub

Sub RemoveEnters()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        '^11 or ^l  New line
        .Text = "^l"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        With Selection.Find
        '^13 or ^p  Carriage return/paragraph mark
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it is helpful. However, my intention is to delete the blank line, so your code delete all the `\n’, that leads to only one line in the whole document.

Comment: ok, I've added a sub-procedure but RemoveBlankLines will only replace one blank line between text and not more.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried and it works fine except the line in the end of the document.

Answer (score 1):

"enter" is the line separator right ? It's platform dependant so I propose the above solution :

```
String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator")
file = new File(filename);
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
String [] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
for(int i=0;i<fileData.length;i++){
    if(fileData[i] != null)
        fileData[i] = fileData[i].replace(separator,"");
}
```

And then you just have to output fileData in a clean doc file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. The code you provided works fine. However, my problem is not solved because, I need to delete the **blank line**. For example, here is a small example:
This’\n’ ‘\n’ is’\n’’ \n’ a’\n’ test’\n’
The objective is to have the following result:
This’\n’ is’\n’ a’\n’ test’\n’

Comment: Add: That's why I use range.getParagraph(i).text().toCharArray()[0], to check if the first char in the line is a '\n' or not, in order to delete the blank line.

Comment: I tried to adopt your method in my java code with range.getParagraph(j).text().replace(separator,"");but it does not work. Nothing happens.